# How to get the result of a job in another job in Flink?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Here is the situation.
I have two data sources, a message queue and a MySQL table, which can be regarded as DataStream and DataSet respectively.I want to start a job based on DataStream to pull data from the message queue and perform some calculation. In the progress of calculation, a job based on DataSet(the MySQL table) is needed, whose OutputFormat should return the result to the DataStream job.
I'm stuck here and need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mix the DataStream and DataSet APIs in the same job. But there are ways to access MySQL from a streaming job. You can:

1. query MySQL from a flatmap
2. use async i/o to do that more efficiently
3. stream in the data from mysql using something like [debezium](http://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mysql/)

Depending on how you want to connect the data from mysql to your other stream(s), you may want to use a CoFlatmapFunction, or a CoProcessFunction.